# D3 components overlapping with other React Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js

I have this App in React

```
<div>
        <h1>Spotify Recommendations</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <button class="button" onClick={this.setRecommendations}>
            Log Into Spotify
          </button>
          <Graphs data={this.state.album_count} margin={this.state.topAlbums} />
          <div className="Graphs">
            <Graphs data={this.state.artist_count} margin={this.state.topArtist} />
          </div>
          <p> below are some recommendations based on your listening history </p>
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <RecommendationResults recommendationResults={this.state.recommendations}
                           onAdd={this.addTrack} />

            <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
                      playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
                      onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
                      onRemove={this.removeTrack}
                      onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want graphs to display between login button and the playlist components but now they are overlapping with the playlist and really no where near the button.

I suspect that this is a CSS problem, I have tried editing my Apps CSS with no luck

```
body,
html,
#root {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
  padding: .77rem 0;
  background-color: #010c3f;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.88rem;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 .highlight {
  color: #6c41ec;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.55rem;
}

.App {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 17% 10% 17%;
  background-color: teal;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}


.App-playlist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.Graphs{

}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

.button{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 8.11rem;
  padding: .77rem 0;
  border-radius: 54px;
  background-color: #010c3f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .833rem;
  transition: background-color .25s;
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

media only screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .App-playlist {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

and here is my D3 component and currently have no CSS attached to this

```
import React from 'react';
//import {Spotify, findUnique} from '../../utils/Spotify';
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Graphs extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawChart();
  }

  drawChart() {
    const data = this.props.data;
    const margin = this.props.margins;
    const h = 300;
    const w = 700;

    const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 700)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .style("margin-left", 300);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => h - (5 * d) - 15)
      .attr("width", 65)
      .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 5)
      .attr("fill", "blue");

    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text((margin) => margin)
      .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => h)
  }

    render(){
      return <div id={"#" + this.props.id} ></div>
    }
}
export default Graphs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are trying to select body tag and append a svg to the body. Instead try selecting the div.

```
const svg = d3.select(`#${this.props.graphId}`)
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 700)
.attr("height", 300)
.style("margin-left", 300);
```

Render function

```
render(){
  return <div id={"#" + this.props.graphId} />
}
```

In JSX part

```
  <Graphs data={this.state.album_count} margin={this.state.topAlbums} graphId={'someid'} />
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that, my graph doesn't display anywhere. I am not sure if there is an error not getting caught or if other components are now covering it up. As opposed to it overlapping other components.

Comment: Update I just used Inspect Element and it is posting div's but there are not SVGs inside

Comment: You are actully trying to append the SVG inside BODY tag not DIV. That's the reason I asked you to change the select function to select DIV's id.There are no BODY tag inside this componenet. That may the reason why no SVG are shown when inspecting inside DIV.

Comment: I changed the select functions to your suggestion. The graphs do not show up. I look at inspect element and there are new <div> inside where I put the components but there are no svg inside the divs 

Code: `const svg = d3.select(\`#${this.props.graphID}\`)` 
and `return <div id={"#" + this.props.graphID} />`

Call: `<Graphs data={this.state.artist_count} margins={this.state.topArtist} graphID={"topArtist"}/>`

Inspect Element: `<div id="#topArtist"></div>`

Comment: [Line Chart](https://codepen.io/stonetip/pen/zoeeOd)
This is very simple line chart example can u try this one?

Comment: I could but I can tell you it will show up just fine. When I have `select("body")` it works and appends to the body of page and overlaps with other components in that area. What I want is for it to appear close to the top between the button and playlist components.

Comment: Can you just share it in jsfiddle or codepen with a sample data aof your's, show that I can check it out.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is that `select(#id_name)` is looking for `id_name` somewhere in the HTML. It couldn't find `id_name` because in `render` we were returning `#id_name` removing the `#` from `render()` solved the issue and now it displays in the correct place.